# How to stop spam accounts

Tags: facebook, verification, account

I have a web site using Facebook Connect where people have a strong incentive to create fake Facebook accounts and login multiple times in order to get more "votes" in my singing competition.

Anyways, I've come up with a strategy to identify these fake accounts and not let them use my site.  (Haven't done the programming yet)

1. If their earliest wall post is more than 30 days old, then validate them.
2. If they have more than 20 friends, then validate them.
3. If their first profile picture is more than 30 days old, then validate them.
4. If their account has been phone verified, then validate them.

Number 4 is the one I'm having trouble with.  One post I read says the GRAPH API has a verified field, but suggests that shows if the email has been verified (but not phone).  This has proven a tough thing to search for. So I'm still unsure if this is possible.

Any comments on my strategy or help with #4 would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have quite the army of fake Facebook accounts and all would already pass 1&3.  A few would pass #2 and only a couple would pass #4.

Comment: Luckily, most of my users realize they need fake accounts at the moment when we launch our competition.  Which lasts 30 days.  But point taken.  We can't stop everyone, but hopefully a high percentage of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use verified and friend count to limit people.  We even put those requirements into our legal terms so there's no misunderstanding.

Comment: Well, as you use `verified`, you validate people who are phone verified. So you don't like your own methods? #4 is not a requirement, it's an option.

Comment: Opps!!  I mean credit card verified.  I think at some point I did sms verification, but never credit card verified.  I'll go edit my comment.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now you lost me. Facebook doesn't exhibit which mean of verification a user used, do they?

Comment: Your comment says:  "    A user is considered verified if she takes any of the following actions:

        Registers for mobile
        Confirms her account via SMS
        Enters a valid credit card
"

Comment: Ok, it looks like "verified" is simply what I need.  I had found a thread here in stackoverflow that said it was for email verification.  But now everything I've read makes me realize this is phone or credit card verification.  T

Comment: If you found my comments helpful, please give me credit by accepting my answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the `verified` field should be what you are looking for. From the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

> A user is considered verified if she takes any of the following
>   actions:
>
> - Registers for mobile
> - Confirms her account via SMS
> - Enters a valid credit card